# Create LINQ intermediate variable the way .Select it does

Tags: c#, linq

I created the following extension:

```
public static class StackTraceExtensions
{
    public static string Callers(this StackTrace trace)
    {
        return string.Join(" < ", trace.GetFrames().Select(sf => sf.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name + "." + sf.GetMethod().Name));
    }
}
```

but calling `GetMethod()` every time isn't a good solution. I looked for some way to create an intermediate variable the way the LINQ `.Select` function it does.

`.Select` is available only for `IEnumerable` and is intended for multiple values, therefore I developed yet another extension, this time for any object:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static TResult Self<TSource, TResult>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector) => selector(source);
}
```

This extension could be used as follows:

```
public static class StackTraceExtensions
{
    public static string Callers(this StackTrace trace)
    {
        return string.Join(" < ", trace.GetFrames().Select(sf => sf.GetMethod().Self(mb => $"{mb.DeclaringType.Name}.{mb.Name}")));
    }
}
```

It allows me to deal here with the intermediate `mb` "variable".

Is there some standard extension that does the same so I don't need to create my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first select the method and then use it in a subsequent `Select`:

```cs
return string.Join(" < ", trace.GetFrames()
    .Select(sf => sf.GetMethod())
    .Select(m => $"{m.DeclaringType.Name}.{m.Name}"));
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really a lot easier than I did.